# Как собрать в ехе код python без отображения консоли?

Tags: python

Как собрать в ехе код python без отображения консоли?

Answer (score 1):

1. Установите pininstaller: `pip install pyinstaller`
2. Пишем команду `pyinstaller -F -w -i( to set up icon on your .exe) main.py`, где `main.py` - ваш python скрипт. Вот что означает каждый флаг: F – этот флаг отвечает за то, чтобы в созданной папке dist, в которой и будет храниться наш исполняемый файл не было очень много лишних файлов, модулей и т.п. -w – этот флаг вам понадобится в том случае, если приложение использует GUI библиотеки (`tkinter`, `PyQt5`, т.п.), оно блокирует создание консольного окна, если же ваше приложение консольное, вам этот флаг использовать не нужно. -i – этот флаг отвечает за установку иконки на наш исполняемый файл, после флага нужно указать полный путь к иконке с указанием её имени. Например: D:\LayOut\icon.ico

Подробнее [тут](https://www.make-info.com/kak-skompilirovat-python-kod-v-exe/)

Comment: флаг F я бы не рекомендовал. выглядит красиво но замедляет запуск вашей программы если она будет увесистая. видимо лишнее время на распаковку этого добра уходит.